# How can I troubleshoot USB drivers on El Capitan

Tags: ios, usb, macos, driver, android

I'm a developer and use [Motorola Device Manager](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/prod_detail/a_id/97326/p/30,6720,9050), and Android File Transfer to work with my Moto X devices.  Prior to the upgrade to El Capitan, I was able to use the USB port, run "adb" and all other developer level commands.

Now, ever since I did a clean install of El Capitan, (not an update), MDM and the system no longer sees my device.  I suspect this has to do with installing the driver After the OS install vs before.  Why? [this forum post](https://forums.motorola.com/posts/49690b6577) seems to indicate that at least one user is able to use the USB port in El Capitan.

Some troubleshooting I've done:

- Verified USB functionality by plugging in an iPad (works)
- Disabled System Integrity Protection (SIP) just in case it breaks the driver
- Uninstalled and reinstalled MDM
- Enabled / disabled developer mode on the phones
- Updated to the latest developer build (besides general release) of El Capitan
- Plugged in the device and ensured that power was flowing.
- Looked at USB power stats in the screen below (unplugging and plugging in)... no change in OS reported power consumption on MacBook Pro 2013

[image]

More troubleshooting steps:

- Plugged device into PC. Works.  (Android 4.4)
- Used a second phone (Different Moto X, Android 5.1), same issues as above.

What else can I try to get OSX to "see" the Android devices?

Soon I will boot into Bootcamp and see if that makes a difference....

Comment: Hit this deadend today. I am trying to setup android studio and motorola x play on mac El Capitan. Did u manage to solve this?